# Search query execution time independent from overall table row count

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

What are the approaches for creating such a DB table (for example, PostgreSQL) and performing such a search query so that the execution time does not depend on the total number of rows in the DB, given that the result of this search query always contains the same subset of rows?

If this is not possible, what are the approaches to achieve the smallest impact of table size on search execution time?

Example: two tables with same structure but different size: `table1` with 1000 rows and `table2` with 1000 000 rows. The tables have the following structure:

1. `id`: primary key column
2. `ts_utc`: UTC timestamp column
3. `user_id`: foreigh key column

On both of this tables we want to find all rows with `user_id` equal to 1 and `ts_utc` greater than yesterday's date. Result for both tables contains the same 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an index, specifically on `(user_id, ts_utc)`.  This works on the query:

```
select t.*
from t
where user_id = 1 and ts_utc >= current_date;
```

The search time is not exactly the same, because the index is stored as a balanced tree.  However, you are dealing with logarithmic differences -- which are very small and hard to measure.